# Delete from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I am trying to delete from multiple tables (in this scenario 6). I tried using INNER JOINS to delete rows from them all in one query, but couldn't get it to work.

Here is my obnoxious work around:

```
        // Delete course and everything linked to it (topics, badges, dotpoints, questions & answers)   
        $topic = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM course_topics WHERE course_id = ".$row_id);    
        foreach ($topic->result() as $t)
        {
            $badge = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM course_topic_badges WHERE topic_id = ".$t->id);    
            foreach ($badge->result() as $b)
            {
                $dotpoint = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM course_topic_dotpoints WHERE badge_id = ".$row_id);
                foreach ($dotpoint->result() as $d)
                {
                    $question = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM quiz_questions WHERE dotpoint_id = ".$d->id);
                    foreach ($question->result() as $q)
                    {
                        $answer = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM quiz_answers WHERE question_id = ".$q->id);
                        foreach ($answer as $a)
                        {
                            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM quiz_answers WHERE question_id = ".$q->id);
                        }
                        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM quiz_questions WHERE dotpoint_id = ".$d->id);
                    }
                    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM course_topic_dotpoints WHERE badge_id = ".$b->id);
                }
                $query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM course_topic_badges WHERE topic_id = ".$t->id);
            }
            $query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM course_topics WHERE course_id = ".$row_id);
        }
        $query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM courses WHERE id = ".$row_id);
```

How can I simplify this?

Comment: Could you explain in English how the "deletes" are related to each other?  Otherwise, if they're *not* related - then separate "delete" statements are your best bet.

Comment: Some foreign key relationships with cascade deletes will ***really*** help you out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this bit:

```
$answer = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM quiz_answers WHERE question_id = ".$q->id); 
foreach ($answer as $a) 
{ 
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM quiz_answers WHERE question_id = ".$q->id); 
}
```

to simply 
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM quiz_answers WHERE question_id = ".$q->id);

The other option (if you have permission) is to set up foreign keys and "ON DELETE CASCADE". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Otherwise, without knowing the database structure it's going to be difficult to receommend much more. You could use sub-selects but you'd still need some cascading.

Another option would be to change the DB structure to include primary keys based off more than one field (e.g course_topic_dotpoints would be "topic_id, badge_id, dotpoint_id") then you can delete more in one go - but this probably requires a fair bit of changing.

Comment: How exactly would I change the db structure to include primary keys?

Comment: Read here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx  as that explains it fairly well.

Comment: Wow. This just opened my eyes. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
you can read more dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
SET @BACKUP_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS; 
SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- Do stuff here

SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@BACKUP_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET @BACKUP_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well  i have created a function for myself which will delete from multiple tables
Here is it

```
    function delete_multiple_rows($table    ,   $condition  ,   $join_condition)
    {
        $table_count    =   count($table);
        $join_count     =   count($join_condition) + 1; 

        if($table_count ==  $join_count)
        {
            if(count($condition)>0)
            {
                $delete_query    =  'DELETE '.  implode(' , ',$table)   .' FROM '.$table[0];

                $counter    =   1;
                foreach($join_condition as $key => $value)
                {
                    $delete_query   .=  ' LEFT JOIN '   .   $table[$counter]    .   ' ON '  .   $key    .   ' = '   .   $value;
                    $counter++;
                }

                $condition_counter  =   1; 

                foreach($condition as $key  => $value)
                {
                    if($condition_counter > 1)
                    {
                        $delete_query   .=  ' AND ';
                    }else{
                        $delete_query   .=  ' WHERE ';
                    }
                    $delete_query   .=  $key    .   ' = '   .   $value;
                    $condition_counter++; 
                }           
                $delete_query;              
                $this->db->query($delete_query);

            }else{
                echo 'This query requires at least 1 where condition.';
            }       
        }else{

            $table_count    =   count($table)   -   1;
            echo 'At least '    .   $table_count    .   ' join conditions must be provided.';
        }
    }
```

HOW TO USE

These are the controller method parameters

```
$table  =   array('table1','table2','table3');
$condition  =   array('id'=>1,'2nd_condition'=>'blah');
$join_condition =   array(
                    'table1.column' =>  'table2.column',
                    'table1.column' =>  'table3.column'
                    );
```

This works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working on sending queries, you should probably set up some triggers in your mysql database.

> delimiter $
>   CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Name BEFORE DELETE ON some_table
>   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
>       DELETE FROM some_other_table WHERE some_id =  NEW.id;
>   END $

Put that in your SQL in PHPMYADMIN, it'll create a trigger called Trigger_Name (doesn't really matter).

Every time you execute a delete function on some_table, it will delete the row in some_other_table with the id you have.

read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html for more information.

Comment: @Sneaksta You're welcome, I should mention, you can have chain reactions using Trigger. If you have trigger of table a affecting table b, and trigger of table b affecting table c. Query sent to table a could affect table b and c.